# Inversão de cada linha de um ficheiro em C

Tags: c

Tou a tentar fazer um programa que basicamente peque cada linha de um ficheiro de texto por ordem inversa, isto é, a linha é mostrada do fim para o início. Por exemplo, a linha 'hello world!' é mostrada da forma '!dlrow olleh'

Até agora tenho este código feito:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define ERR_IO 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "debug.h"
#include "memory.h"
#include "invert_line_file.h"

void invert_line_file(char *filename){

    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");    

    if (fptr==NULL){
        ERROR(1, "Erro ao abrir o ficheiro %s", filename);
    }

    int cont=0;
    char *line=NULL;
    size_t line_size=0;
    int i=0, j=0;
    int size;

    printf("\nFile '%s'", filename);
    while (getline(&line, &line_size, fptr)!=-1){
        size=strlen(line);
        while((size_t)i<strlen(line)){
            for (i=0 ; (line[i]!='\0') ; i++){
                for (j=0; j<i; j++){
                    char tmp = line[j];
                    line[j] = line[size-1-j];
                    line[size-1-j] = tmp;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        i=0;
        j=0;
        cont++;
        printf("\n%x: '%s'", cont, line);
    }

    if (!feof(fptr)){
        ERROR(1, "Erro ao ler do ficheiro %s", filename);
    }
}
```

O meu problema é que por exemplo com um ficheiro (data.txt) com o seguinte conteudo:

```
Gabriel
Joao
Pedro
Rui
Andre
Joni
Goncalo
Ana
Silvia
Maria
```

A saida no fim de executar o programa é:

```
File 'data.txt'
1: '
leirbaG'
2: 'Joao
'
3: '
ordeP'
4: '
iuR'
5: '
erdnA'
6: 'Joni
'
7: '
olacnoG'
8: '
anA'
9: 'Silvia
'
a: '
airaM'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sua inversão da `string` está demasiado complexa:

```
while((size_t)i<strlen(line)){
    for (i=0 ; (line[i]!='\0') ; i++){
        for (j=0; j<i; j++){
            char tmp = line[j];
            line[j] = line[size-1-j];
            line[size-1-j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
i=0;
j=0;
```

Você tem 3 loops para fazer uma inversão. Para ser honesto nem consegui perceber exatamente como chegou a estes 3 `loops` porque apenas 1 resolve o seu problema:

```
for (i = 0, j = size-1; i < size/2; ++i, j--){
    char tmp = line[j];
    line[j] = line[size-1-j];
    line[size-1-j] = tmp;
}
```

Repare que eu vou até metade de string e troco diretamente com o caratere correspondente a partir do fim. Também não voltei a colocar o `i` e `j` a `0` pois o `for` encarrega-se de inicializar essas duas variáveis com os valores que interessam.

O outro problema tem a ver com a quebra de linha que ficou na string quando a leu com `getline`. Isso dá aquele <kbd>Enter</kbd> a mais que vê na saida. Consegue resolver bem esse problema procurando pelo `\n` que lá esta e colocando o terminador nesse mesmo local:

```
line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = '\0';
```

A função [`strcspn`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/) acha a posição de um determinado texto numa string e devolve-a. Caso não ache nada devolve o tamanho da string.

Esta teria que ser aplicada antes da inversão, passando o seu código do `while(getline..)` a ser:

```
while (getline(&line, &line_size, fptr)!=-1){
    line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = '\0';
    size=strlen(line);

    for (i = 0, j = size-1; i < size/2; ++i, j--){
        char tmp = line[j];
        line[j] = line[size-1-j];
        line[size-1-j] = tmp;
    }
    cont++;
    printf("\n%x: '%s'", cont, line);
}
```

Com essas duas alterações já tem a saida que pretende:

```
File 'data.txt'
1: 'leirbaG'
2: 'oaoJ'
3: 'ordeP'
4: 'iuR'
5: 'erdnA'
6: 'inoJ'
7: 'olacnoG'
8: 'anA'
9: 'aivliS'
a: 'airaM'
```